# Chrome extension identity api fetches same user every time?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I have created a chrome extension application but i have the following problem

1. user 1 logged in to the gmail account.
2. Install the chrome extension
3. extension fetches logged user data using chrome identity api
4. user 1 logs out , user 2 logs in
5. Uninstall and reinstall the extension
6. extension again fetches the user 1 data

How can i fix this issue. Any Suggestions is appreciated

Comment: So, where's the question?

Answer (score 1):

Identity api will try to pull the logged user in the chrome not the gmail . Go to settings and click the option for disconnect your google account .